# String.format changes dot to a comma

Tags: vb.net

i have this line:

```
Dim url As String = String.Format("http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a={2}&from={0}&to={1}", fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper(), amount)
```

Amount consists of this:

0.5

But when add a watch onto url then i see that it is converted it to a comma, like 0,5. Why does it do this and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the culture settings in the code:

```
Dim US As New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim web As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
Dim url As String = String.Format("http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a={2}&from={0}&to={1}", fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper(), amount.ToString("", US))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of local settings of your OS. You can change default decimal seperator as explained [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/decimal-and-thousand-separators-for-number-and/35756e7c-5cf5-4003-9920-bf5d4b98dd85).

Briefly, it states that 
"Control Panel/Regional and Language Options/Format" tab is used to adjust decimal and thousand separators for number and currency formats.